# element.find is not a function

Tags: node.js, rest, api, express

I'm learning how to make a REST Api and copied the [tutorial's](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4) code in exactly, but it's giving me this error:

```
TypeError: Bear.find is not a function
at /Users/madisontaskett/instaApi/server.js:67:14
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/madisontaskett/instaApi/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/Users/madisontaskett/instaApi/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
at next (/Users/madisontaskett/instaApi/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:14)
at Route.dispatch (/Users/madisontaskett/instaApi/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/madisontaskett/instaApi/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /Users/madisontaskett/instaApi/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (/Users/madisontaskett/instaApi/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
at next (/Users/madisontaskett/instaApi/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
at /Users/madisontaskett/instaApi/server.js:35:5
```

Here's my code snippet:

```
.get(function(req, res) {

    var Bear = require('./api/models/instaApiModel');
    Bear.find(function(err, bears) {
        if (err)
            res.render(err);

        res.json(bears);
    });
});
```

Comment: What is in `instaApiModel`

Comment: The error indicates that `.find()` is not a valid function within the `Bear` object.  Meaning your `instaApiModel` does not define `find`.  If you wrote `instaApiModel` yourself then backtrack through your code and figure out where you went wrong.  If `instaApiModel` is a prebuilt module and you are following docs on how to use it, then perhaps your usage does not match the release version (i.e. you are using an outdated version).  Either way, without knowing more about `instaApiModel` it's hard to know.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is about loading the Bear Model.

```
// Bear models lives here
var Bear = require('./app/models/bear');
```

You also need to make sure that you create a model as follows:

```
// app/models/bear.js    
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

var BearSchema = new Schema({
    name: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Bear', BearSchema);
```

Please refer to [this link](https://github.com/scotch-io/node-api/blob/master/server.js) for complete source code.